# Unit test for !String.isblank()

Tags: unit-test

I dont know how I can create  test case for

```
 urlId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id') ; 
  urlId2 = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('pb') ; 
  if (!String.isBlank(urlId)){ 
    opportunity = [Select Id from Opportunity where id =:urlId];
    //products = [Select IsActive, Product2Id, UnitPrice , Name from PricebookEntry where Pricebook2Id =: urlId2 ];
    selectedPriceBook = urlId2;

    refreshPage();

      oppID = opportunity.id;

      qot = new Quote();

      qot.OpportunityId = oppID;
      System.debug('qot.PoortunityID' + qot.OpportunityId );
      qot.Pricebook2Id = selectedPriceBook ;
      qot.ExpirationDate = date.today()+30;
     }
```

I thought perhaps this would work

```
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id' + opp.id) ; 
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('pb' + customPB.id) ; //Pricebook2 ID
```

Answer (score 1):

To set page parameters in a testmethod

```
ApexPages.currentpage().getParameters().put('id',opp.id);
```

where  `opp` refers to some mocked Opportunity

BTW - I like to use static final variables for all my page parameters so the testemthod and prod class(es) always use the same parameter value, properly cased

as in

```
ApexPages.currentpage().getParameters().put(CONSTANTS.PGPARAM_ID,opp.id);
```

Comment: I'd advise against using final static variables in a class called constants. The problem is that they take a non-zero time to initialize the class, and as it grows in size, you'll start having performance problems on all code paths that use constants. As proof, at my last job, I managed to shave about 500ms off of almost *every* transaction in the system by changing the constants class we had to use getters instead: `public String PGPARAM_ID { get { return 'pg'; } }` This also has downsides (e.g. functions also take time), but is far more efficient than final static initializers.

Comment: @sfdcfox -- thank you!   this is great information and I'll adapt my CONSTANTS class forthwith.  There were so many times when I would inherit code from others with string literals scattered all over the place with sometimes inconsistent capitalization and spaces that I vowed to centralize all such refs to never have to debug a problem with a string literal ever again.    Now I get a performance boost!